# Installing Pillow error

Tags: python, django, clang, pip, osx-mavericks

I am trying to syncdb a new project I cloned. After installing the requirements, I noticed that I needed to install PIL, or Pillow for that matter in order to get syncdb to work.

Here is what happened when I ran `pip install pillow`:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

After searching through stack I tried doing these commands:

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
sudo -E pip install pillow
```

and ultimately got:

```
In file included from _imagingtk.c:19:

    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/tk.h:78:11: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found

    #       include <X11/Xlib.h>

                    ^

    1 error generated.

    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

At least no clang, but still pillow doesn't work. I have tried some other methods including ignoring flags and whatnot, but none of them seemed to get pillow working in my virtualenv. Any Idea what I can do? I am running Mavericks 10.9.2

Comment: How about using good old fashioned PIL?  `pip install pil`

Comment: You might need to do `apt-get build-dep python-imaging` to install the required dependencies (in the case of this error, `libx11-dev`)

Comment: @sk1p he can't use `apt-get`, he's on OS X

Answer (score 2):

I am using OS X El Capitan, and this worked for me.

1. Close your virtualenv active terminal window.
2. Open new terminal and run `sudo xcode-select --install`, it will take some time to finish.
3. After finish that open a new terminal and run `pip install Pillow`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Homebrew installed on your Mac? If you do, the Pillow docs recommend that you install using the following command:

```
brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2
```

See http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#os-x-installation for more details.

Again, if you've got Homebrew, you can also take a look at [homebrew-python](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python), which provides a brew formula for Pillow.

Comment: Okay ive ran your command and I also ran 'brew install Homebrew/python/pillow', this still gives me a similar error: http://pastebin.com/sGc4TBDt Am I doing something wrong? Why is this raising such a stink in relation to Xcode?

Comment: According to the [Homebrew and Python](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python) documentation, you should not be trying to run `brew` from inside a virtualenv. `brew` will always install into /usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages (and this is just and fair). You should leave your virtualenv before running `brew` and you will need to recreate your virtualenv with --system-site-packages after you install pillow.